# document.getElementById not working inside function

Tags: javascript

I am getting a strange problem while using `document.getElementById` inside a function.
I have a form in modal window ([Highslide](http://highslide.com/)). While the form is submitting, I am just calling function foo.Inside foo I am just selecting form elements by ID using `document.getElementById`. But doesn't present value, just returns default value.
I tried jQuery html but it doesn't work.

My code

```
function foo(){
    var name = document.getElementById('yname').value; 
    // it just returns default value(null).
} 

<form onsubmit="return foo();">.......</form>
```

These things are happening in Wordpress theme.

[Working location](http://cratecreative.com/kosherwedding/abigaels/)

[Modal form is existing here](http://awesomescreenshot.com/020fnvie5)

Comment: did you tried returning name from function? put ` return name;' in function.

Comment: Your name field has an ID of `yname`.

Answer (score 2):

(Looking at the live code) Is that an attempt to grab the form field with an **id** of `yname`?  Have you tried using `yname` instead of `name`?  (your HTML contains `input name="name" id="yname"`).

Comment: In that case, while the form is displayed you have TWO elements with an id of yname.  You'd be better of doing `onsubmit="return avalid(this)"` to pass the form reference into the javascript handler, then you can grab values simply using `form.elements['name'].value` etc. (assuming you also change `function avalid(form)...`

Comment: thanks for that. it works so i gave +1,but what is the wrong here.Because i want print the ajax response  .But i couldn't select the element "ajax_validation_response".please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have

```
id="name"
```

anywhere on page

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` should be provided with `id` not `name` attribute